# Parse: remove user and its related records

Tags: javascript, objective-c, parse-platform

I have Parse table with entities.
User - default class
Commets - class with pointer to _User entity.

I need to delete user from entity User together with all its comments, located in Comments entity:

Right now I have JS Cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteUser", function(request, response) {
                   var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
                   var query = new Parse.Query(User);
                   var userID = request.params.userID;
                   query.get(userID,{
                             success: function(User) {
                             var message = 'success';

                             User.destroy({
                                          useMasterKey: true ,
                                            success:function() {
                                            response.success(message);
                                            return;
                                            },
                                            error:function(error) {
                                            response.error('Could not delete object '+ User.id);
                                            return;
                                            }
                                            });
                             },
                             error: function(object, error) {
                             var message = 'User could not found';
                             response.error(message);
                             }
                             });
                   });
```

It's removing user only.
How I can combine to remove also records from other entity by user?

Thanks for advance

Comment: You can register a handler with [afterDelete](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-afterdelete) method.

Answer (score 5):

As eth3lbert pointed out in the comments, you should use an afterDelete hook that gets called after the User object has been deleted. You can kick off any other delete operations you want.

However, there is a little gotcha, the before* and after* methods get killed after 3 seconds of wall clock time which might lead to unwanted results depending on the amount of data that you need to delete.

The best solution for you is to setup a background job (they can run for up to 15 minutes), schedule it to run, lets say once every day, and do any cleanup work in that job.

You could create a simple table for that, that contains the objectIds of deleted users, whenever your `afterDelete` method gets called, you add the deleted users id into that table, your background job then queries that table on run and deletes the content that was associated with it.

Comment: Thank, the issue is closed. I have written one function thats deletes all records.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete user easily from user request as below.

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('deleteUser', async (req) => {
  const user = req.user;
  return user.destroy({ useMasterKey: true});
})
```

and add additional deleting logic related to `User`.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issues particularly while deleting after searching using parameters other than objectid.