# Delete an PFUser as another Admin PFUser

Tags: swift, parse-platform, back4app

I using back4app service and as admin I would like to fetch `PFUser` records and delete some of them if needed.

Currently I am getting error:

```
User cannot be deleted unless they have been authenticated.
```

I logged in as a PFUser. Is are any possibilities to do it via masterKey or smth like this?

Answer (score 0):

The best option I see here is to use cloud code as you would not want to give authenticated users permission to delete other users.

So basically you would have to write a Cloud code function where you retrieve users and delete them.

Have a look at this guide below

https://help.back4app.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045500871-How-to-update-a-user-

Comment: I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366161/parse-remove-user-and-its-related-records) as well but user was not removed, I even don't see any logs. I've tried afterDelete function as well as deleteUser function. So calling this code pfUser.deleteInBackground { (result, error) in swift does not even looks call Parse cloud function. I've double checked the file is there.